# SVN incosistent eol when adding file

Tags: linux, svn, command-line

Quiet simply I am trying to add new files to my repository, my command goes like this:

```
svn add * --force
```

but this produces:

> svn: File 'install/config.xml.php' has inconsistent newlines svn:
>   Inconsistent line ending style

The thing is that this file is not yet under version control, so when I try to *propdel* or anything similar it doesn't work.

I am sure this file is not under version control because *svn status* shows this:

> ?       install/version
>   ?       install/config.xml.php

I have already enabled the autoprops in svn default config but this did not help.

Any ideas?

Btw: this is a server, so no GUI.

Comment: Remove "Inconsistent linending" of file before adding to SVN, autoprops can help later with already versioned data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vim` makes it easy to force line endings to entirely CRLF or entirely CR.

```
:set ff=unix
:wq
```

`d2u`, `dtox`, `dos2unix`, are some names for simple utilities that are often installed on systems to do this task. You could also use the standard `tr(1)` utility:

```
tr -d '\r' < input > output
```

Answer (score 0):

While working on Windows OS use Notepad ++:

```
Edit -> EOL Conversion.

 - Windows Format
 - UNIX/OSX Format
 - Old Mac Format
```

You have current format information in the status bar.